# How to check if a type never be a valid generic argument?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

The code I have so far is as the following, what I want to solve is to get rid of the try-catch:

```
public static bool IsNeverValidGenericArgument(this Type type) {
    var elementType=type.GetElementType();

    if(null!=elementType) {
        if(type.IsArray)
            try {
                typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
                return false;
            }
            catch(ArgumentException) {
            }
            catch(TypeLoadException) {
            }

        return true; // pointer or byref 
    }

    return
        typeof(void)==type||typeof(RuntimeArgumentHandle)==type
        ||
        typeof(ArgIterator)==type||typeof(TypedReference)==type;
}
```

I'm trying to write the code of dynamic type construction, and my code will invoke `GetInterfaces()` on each type passed, but some of the types passed by the consumers' code may cause a `TypeLoadException` in `RuntimeType` internally(e.g. `typeof(ArgIterator).MakeArrayType().MakeArrayType()` in 3.5, but not 4.0+), I need to check if it is never a valid generic argument in the first place. try-catch works, but no good.

Note that the cases that it throws **may vary with different version of .Net framework**.

---

**Edit:**

An alternative version of the method is:

```
public static bool IsNeverValidGenericArgument(this Type type) {
    var elementType=type.GetElementType();

    if(null!=elementType) {
        if(type.IsArray)
            return elementType.IsNeverValidGenericArgument();

        return true; // pointer or byref 
    }

    return
        typeof(void)==type||typeof(RuntimeArgumentHandle)==type
        ||
        typeof(ArgIterator)==type||typeof(TypedReference)==type;
}
```

But this will reports some types as invalid which in fact would **not** cause the exception in `RuntimeType`, such as `typeof(ArgIterator).MakeArrayType(2).MakeArrayType()`.

I know some types are not nomally used, but I can't avoid them to be used in the consumers' code.

Comment: Why do you actually want to check this? Does the compiler perform this kind of check if you would use generics?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Since there's not a syntax that the consumers' code can specify variadic type arguments, so I can only use a variadic method to receive the type arguments, just as what `MakeGenericType` does.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If you would write the following code in a C# program, would you get a compiler error? `new List<WhateverTypeThrowsAnException>();` If not, why do you need to handle such a special case? In other words, how do you plan to use `IsNeverValidGenericArgument`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: The `WhateverTypeThrowsAnException` is not allowed by the compiler. I'm constructing types dynamically, as long as it is possible made with `MakeXXXXType` and allowed by the CLR, I should not exclude them. I invoke `IsNeverValidGenericArgument` in a wrapped version of `GetInterfaces`, and it may invoked on all types in an assembly to compare for polymorphism.

Comment: `typeof(ArgIterator).MakeArrayType().MakeArrayType().GetInterfaces()` never throws for me (32/64 bit, .NET 2 -> 4). Do you have a consistent reproducing sample?

Comment: @SimonMourier: I'm sure it throws with 3.5 of x86. It doesn't perhaps because of the assembly cache of your environment .. ?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "assembly cache of my environment". I tested a console app. GetInterfaces() gives me back 7 types.

Comment: What is really wrong with Try Catch? For better performance, you could easily cache results of Try Catch in a static dictionary that will live till the life of application. Cached dictionary for results will be faster after first run.

Comment: @AkashKava: That's a good idea if there's no better way than throwing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to construct a generic type with an argument of `typeof(ArgIterator).MakeArrayType().MakeArrayType()`, it's internal native CLR code that throws the exception. The most important takeaway from that fact is that it's a CLR implementation detail that throws, and it's not part of a standard or a publicly-exposed API that determines the validity of a generic type argument. That means there's no good way to determine whether or not the generic type can be constructed without actually trying it. *EDIT: That also means there's no good way to determine whether something will work on a particular version of the CLR and not work on another.*

But, more importantly, if you try to construct a generic type with an invalid argument, that is truly an exceptional case, and the correct course of action is to throw an exception. I can't speak to what your code does, but if you're worried about your consumers invoking it with classes that cause `TypeLoadException`s to be thrown, perhaps you should let those errors bubble up so the consumer knows that there's an issue.

**TL;DR: You probably shouldn't be doing whatever you're trying to do to handle the exception case. Just let it throw.**

Comment: Let's say you have some UI for specifying generic types that gives you a drop-down list of available types for the different parameters. You want to filter them to not include types that are invalid. Since your assemblies may include thousands of types, you don't want to try to construct each one and catch the exceptions (and you certainly don't want those exceptions shown to the user); you just want to be able to look at some properties on the type to know whether to exclude them from you list.

Comment: @Gabe: Your example is very similar to my scenario.

Comment: @Ken why don't you tell us more about your exact scenario? That way maybe we can help come up with a better solution.

Comment: @AdamMaras: You surprised me .. I'd think that I described clearly in the question that I'm trying to write the code of dynamic type construction, and replied the questions by the comments.

Comment: @Ken you misunderstand; I can see exactly *what* you're trying to do. I'm telling you it would help more if I knew *why* you were doing it.

Comment: @AdamMaras: Oh .. I'm afraid that it would contains a lot of code which might consider irrelevant and make the question much unclear ..

Comment: @Ken I'm not looking for code, I'm looking for **purpose**. Tell me in words, not in code, what the end result of all this code will be.

Comment: @AdamMaras: Okay, I'm trying. A case would be, search all the types in mscorlib, including all array types, pointer/byref types, generic types which can be made from those types. Then find the best match of polymorphism of the types which given by the consumers' code. And then dynamically build a type which derived from the best match if it is inheritable, or encapsulate if it was not. For the polymorphism, I consider the interfaces of the given types.

Comment: @Ken Alright, we're getting closer now. But I still don't understand the end goal. Let's talk in broader terms; if I give you some code (the consumer code in your example) what would that code look like, and what would the final result be once your code is finished doing its thing?

Comment: For example, the consumers' code says `MakeMyType(typeof(IList<char>), typeof(Array))` then my code are going to build a type encapsulate `char[]` and exposes all the interfaces that contracted by `IList<char>` and `Array`. If it was `MakeMyType(typeof(ArgIterator.MakeArrayType(2).MakeArrayType()), typeof(IEnumerable))`, I'll do the simliar thing as the former case. The type is instantiable or not, doesn't matter, since the interface methods are not guaranteed to be invoked. This is just an example for elaboration, there is, in fact, an ultimate base type which is defined in my code.

Comment: Well, it's difficult to make the decision of *just let it throw* whereas nothing need to be handled with this exception. It would become an **eagerly throwing** while the execution may not be necessarily broken by the attempt. But seems there is, currently, no better way.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem due to your customer potentially passing in types that don't have a valid public parameter-less constructor? If that is the case, you could restrict the input they are allowed to send you by adding a condition to your generic method:

```
public class MyClass<T>
    where T : new()
{

}
```

This code will only allow generic types T that have a public constructor with no parameters. You can find more info on the [where clause here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

I don't know how you have your variadic type arguments implemented, but you could take in a params collection of type T with the above clause added, like so:

```
public class MyClass<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public void MyMethod(params T[] items)
    {
        //...Do stuff...
    }
}
```

That would let them pass in as many items as they wanted, but restrict them to generic types that you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you added some test cases so that we coders could know specifically what you expect.  But you offered a bounty so I am seeing if this gets close to what you want.

**results of code below:**

*Test has definition Test<>

Actual Type is UserQuery+Test`1[System.Int32]*

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether this type has the specified definition in its ancestry.
    /// </summary>   
    public static bool HasGenericDefinition(this Type type, Type definition)
    {
        return GetTypeWithGenericDefinition(type, definition) != null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the actual type implementing the specified definition from the
    /// ancestry of the type, if available. Else, null.
    /// </summary>
    public static Type GetTypeWithGenericDefinition(this Type type, Type definition)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if (definition == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("definition");
        if (!definition.IsGenericTypeDefinition) throw new ArgumentException("The definition needs to be a GenericTypeDefinition", "definition");

        if (definition.IsInterface)
            foreach (var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
                if (interfaceType.IsGenericType && interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == definition)
                    return interfaceType;

        for (Type t = type; t != null; t = t.BaseType)
            if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == definition)
                return t;

        return null;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Type a = typeof(Test<int>);
    Type b = typeof(Test<>);
    if(a.HasGenericDefinition(b)) Console.WriteLine("Test<int> has definition Test<>");
    Type c = a.GetTypeWithGenericDefinition(b);
    Console.WriteLine("Actual Type is {0}", c.ToString());
}

public class Test<T>
{
    public Test()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you don't need throwing in the code. If the arguments are illegal for doing the things just leave it. I'm trying to find a way which not throw.

Comment: You could just return null instead but they are just safety exceptions protecting you from trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see it can be done *much* better than what you have already. Here's my version:

```
// Predicts whether the given type cannot be used as a type argument.
public static bool IsNeverValidGenericArgument(this Type type)
{
  if (type == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

  // Pointer types and ByRef types.
  if (type.IsPointer || type.IsByRef)
    return true;

  // The following four special cases were found by reflecting through all types in mscorlib.dll, System.dll, and System.Core.dll.
  // The list may be different in other versions of the framework.
  var exceptions = new HashSet<Type>
  {
    typeof(ArgIterator), typeof(RuntimeArgumentHandle), typeof(TypedReference), typeof(void),
  };
  return exceptions.Contains(type);
}
```

Note that this considers only if the type system will construct a closed generic type with `type` as its type argument. There are types that are quite meaningless, such as:

```
typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Math))  // will work
// but C# does not allow the notation IList<Math>
```

where `System.Math` is a static class (abstract and sealed type). My method will still return `false` for static classes like that.

Some types don't even exist, such as `type = typeof(int).MakeByRefType().MakeArrayType()` (will throw), so these bastards can't be checked by my method.

Comment: By ref types fail with any of `MakeXXXXType`s. The static types what I didn't check for, are allowed by the CLR, I don't know why it even allows that whereas it's meaningless in any high-level language of .NetFx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update to your "alternative" version of the code that addresses the issue with ArgIterator.

```
    public static bool IsNeverValidGenericArgument(this Type type)
    {
        return type.IsNeverValidGenericArgument(true);
    }

    private static bool IsNeverValidGenericArgument(this Type type, bool isRoot)
    {
        var elementType = type.GetElementType();

        if (null != elementType)
        {
            if (type.IsArray)
                return elementType.IsNeverValidGenericArgument(false);

            return true; // pointer or byref 
        }

        if (isRoot)
        {
            return
                typeof(void) == type || typeof(RuntimeArgumentHandle) == type
                ||
                typeof(ArgIterator) == type || typeof(TypedReference) == type;
        }
        else
        {
            return (typeof(void) == type || typeof(TypedReference) == type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The story is much complicated than this .. you might want to try it with 3.5 and 4.0+ by making various jagged/multidimentional array and to see the strange different behaviors of the runtime.

Comment: I will have a look.  I only tested in 4.0 with the situation you mentioned.  Do you have any other types I should test with?   I don't like that these functions mention specific types when they really should be able to work from metadata.

Comment: These specific types are, in fact, special types for compiler use. There should not be too much types like these. If you are going to test more types, I'd suggest `MakeXXXXType`s.

Comment: I tested with 3.5 and 4.0 and type you mentioned as well as a couple of others.  I don't know what to look for but I didn't observe the strange different behaviors.